Installation of anRichment R package: the source doesn't work, Horvath Lab site down again
Where can I currently find anRichment R package? The following page is not available due to web page down:
source("https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/GeneAnnotation/installAnRichment.R")

The source web page https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/GeneAnnotation/installAnRichment.R is unavailable. In addition, the package anRichment can't be found neither on GitHub, nor on Bioconudctor. My question was, if there any other source of anRichment R package installation file or code. I guess, the problem is quite clear.

Apologies for the unavailable web page. The packages are temporarily available from dropbox under this link.

Thanks a lot for the prompt answer and installation files!
